# intellij mass refactoring using macros

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

I am working on a project in intellij using java and spring.
I want to change in multiple files my api's in a similar way like this:

instead of:

```java
public void someApi(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    someThrift thriftRequest = getThrift(...);
    someOtherThrift thriftResponse = …
    setThriftResponse(...);
}
```

use this:

```java
@ThriftResponse
public someThrift getReports(@ThriftRequestBody someThrift thriftRequest) throws Exception {
    someOtherThrift thriftResponse = …
    return thriftResponse;
}
```

is there a way to achieve this using some sort of a macro?
this kind of code spans on multiple files that all have the same suffix in their name as well

thank you

Comment: You can use Structural replace for that. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fIPr_ANBpFk and https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace.html

Comment: @KonstantinAnnikov thanks it seems great, I didn't know this feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, you can use [Structural search and replace](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace.html). It allows you to search and replace fragment of codes using a template defined with variables constraint by count numbers, regular expressions, and even Groovy scripts.

The easiest way to create a template is to browse the list of existing ones, find one similar to what you want to achieve and modify it.